# Colonists on an icy moon confront an alien machine

Tags: story-identification

A young man joins the hunt for an alien artifact or machine that appears randomly. Pretty sure it was from the 80s.

I only remember certain bits including:

- Either Jupiter or Saturn moons (Ganymede I think)
- Ammonia lakes.
- Dogs and monkeys with cybernetic enhancements.
- Turkey meat grown in vats (called lurkey)

**What is the name of this story?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a references to both Ganymede and "Lurkey" in [Against Infinity](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=V57Kc8XzWPUC&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=ganymede%20lurkey&source=bl&ots=yplDkW0AiN&sig=B8A351YNzA0mr9ruiKIP8Kn5EwY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSrvHuoerOAhXqB8AKHW1-DiYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=ganymede%20lurkey&f=false) by Gregory Benford

> *FOR BREAKFAST THEY had sharp-root and coffee and lurkey. The heavy smells mingled, stirring Manuel's stomach until it growled. The lurkey was good — thick slices cut from the old slab at Sidon, meat that still had cells in it from the first turkey to survive the voyage out. For years the original Settlement families from old Mexico had lived on it and very little else.*